# SQL Server table rename method

Tags: sql-server-2008

how can i rename a table which has contain '.' symbol in the name? ex: `sp_rename Table_1.2 , Table_12`

this sp does not work when table name contains a (.) Dot symbol. is there any another way for renaming a table ?

Comment: `sp_rename quotename(Table_1.2) , quotename(Table_12)`

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets and single quotes

```
sp_rename '[Table_1.2]', Table_12
```